# AFNetworking setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password: vs. setDefaultCredential

Tags: ios, afnetworking, basic-authentication

I'm using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and associated goodies, and I've subclassed [AFOAuth2Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client) to do some OAuth work with tokens and so forth.

For testing purposes, I'm working on a dev server that requires a username & password to access the pages/API endpoints.  When I browse to one of the pages, I get a little dialog box, enter the credentials, and I'm good for some time.  As I understand it this is "Basic Authentication" or "Basic Access Authentication".

So when I instantiate my AFOAuth2Client subclass, I use

```
[self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"user" password:@"pass"];
```

with the appropriate username and password that I would type into my browser when prompted, but when I attempt to access the dev server, using the `HTTPOperationWithRequest:` method, I get rejected.

So instead, when I instantiate the client, I try:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"user" password:@"pass" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
[self setDefaultCredential:credential];
```

And this works fine for all requests I make; the server lets me in.

Now as far as I understand, the first method is setting the `Authorization:` HTTP header with my credentials, and the second method tells my request that when it gets challenged, set the `Authorization:` HTTP header with my credentials...same thing, no?

Why would the first method fail and the second one succeed?